# Does the order of the columns in an CSV file affect the performance of my neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, python

**It's a classification problem.**

I have a big dataset ( `CSV` file) of flights, where each flight is depicted as a set of variables ( `airport_of_departure,  airport_of_arrival, date_of_departure, etc`). Each flight is also characterized by a variable `px_no` that is associated with the number of passengers.

My neural network aims to predict this variable of the flights, for which this particular variable is unknown. Do you think that the order of the variables ( `airport_of_departure, airport_of_arrival, etc`) in my training set affects the outcome? For example, faster/slower learning, better/worse score.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely abstract perspective, it absolutely should not in this case. Practically, it also shouldn't, but some library component might be implemented in a slightly dodgy way so that you do see minor differences, but this is more of a bug than anything.